# How to sum in each cell until a condition is met

Tags: microsoft-excel

Employees can buy products from our inventory and we can deduct the cost monthly in their checks. We help them by setting a small monthly deduction of either: $25,$50,$75 or $100.

I need help with a formula that I can drag in each cell and tell me when to stop deducting the agreed amount.

In the link below you could see how I'll be needing a formula that I can drag and can give me the desired result in Dec, Apr, or May.
Thank you in advance!

[image: excel sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use some nested ifs:

```
=IF(COLUMN()=3,IF($B2<=A2,$B2,$A2),IF(SUM(B2:$C2)=$A2,"",IF(SUM(B2:$C2)+$B2>$A2,$A2-SUM(B2:$C2),$B2)))
```

[image]

Comment: it works like a charm !!!! Thank you!!!!!

Comment: @ALEX305 please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.